# Vue image src not rendering data return

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Does anyone know how to properly call in a link to a HTML img src? I tried all ways and I'm not able too.

Here is what I have inside my `vue.js` app loop:

```
<div class="level-left">
    <span class="icon" aria-hidden="true">
        <img src="{{app.icon_url}}" />
    </span>
    <span>{{app.ID}}</span>
    <span>{{app.name}}</span>
</div>
```

Here is the image:
[image]

Name and ID are pulling in as needed, but for some reason, the image won't as shown below:
[image]

Comment: You cannot use handlebars syntax in attributes: use `v-bind` instead: ["Mustaches cannot be used inside HTML attributes"](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use the following attempt and it worked:

```
<span class="icon" aria-hidden="true">
    <img :src="app.icon_url" />
</span>
```

Not sure how binding works, but will read into it.